# Literal does not match

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, jasper-reports

In jasper report with oracle database where "

```
 (c_order.dateordered >= $P{DateOrdered1} OR $P{DateOrdered1} = '1900/01/01')
AND (c_order.dateordered <= $P{DateOrdered2} OR $P{DateOrdered2} = '1900/01/01') "
```

is not working by throwing the Literals does not match error.

Comment: Is `$P{DateOrdered1}` an actual Oracle date, or a string representation in YYYY/MM/DD format? That will affect which part needs an explicit `to_date()` conversion.

Comment: You just didnt tell the database, what could the format of the default date string..Either specify the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or explicitly specify the format using `to_date()` conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(c_order.dateordered >= $P{DateOrdered1} OR $P{DateOrdered1} = to_date('1900/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD'))
AND (c_order.dateordered <= $P{DateOrdered2} OR $P{DateOrdered2} = to_date('1900/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD'))
```